# how to unit test a component wrapped inside react-hotKeys

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I do have component like

```
<Hotkeys id="hot-keys-id" keyMap={KEY_MAP} handlers={this.handlers}>
<MyComponent/>
<Hotkeys/>
```

i am trying to simulate event onKeyDown it doesn't work

```
const someRandom = jest.fn();
const component = mount(<MyComponent onKeyDown={someRandom} />);
component.find('#hot-keys-id').at(0).simulate('focus');
component.find('#hot-keys-id').at(0).simulate('keyDown', { keyCode: 81 });
expect(someRandom).toBeCalled();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at the tests for that library as they define a lot of techniques they use to verify the behavior in hotkeys. Most of them I found skimming use a helper package using `.simulate('keyPress', {})` and `.simulate('keyUp', {})`, so I suspect that's what they're listening to.

https://github.com/greena13/react-hotkeys/tree/master/test

and the support library

https://github.com/greena13/react-hotkeys/blob/9974edc258e27f635bc303df5539eceb79bc55be/test/support/FocusableElement.js#L6